# With OpenCV T-API, why pure GPU load causes very high CPU load?

Tags: c++, performance, opencv, opencl

At first look, [T-API](http://opencv.org/platforms/opencl.html) works great, you just have to replace the cv::Mat with cv::UMat, and your code runs many times faster.

The problem is, while pure GPU code is running, the CPU is also at 100%.

In this way, you can not fully utilize the CPU.

Here is the code, tested with OpenCV 3.1.0, where there is no memory transfer, but pure GPU computations, and I expect this to cause 0% CPU load, but in practice it is 100% or more (tested on many machines).

```
void test_tapi_inf() {
    int sum = 0;
    cv::UMat mat(1000, 1000, CV_8UC1);
    mat.setTo(1);

    while (true) {
        int64 tick1 = cv::getTickCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            sum = cv::sum(mat)[0];
        }
        int64 tick2 = cv::getTickCount();
        printf("time: %f, sum: %d\n", (tick2 - tick1) / cv::getTickFrequency(), sum);
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
time: 0.961175, sum: 1000000
time: 1.097721, sum: 1000000
...
```

It works 5 times faster than the cv::Mat version, loads the GPU, but, unfortunately, loads the CPU to 100% or more.

I have noticed that a number of threads are also spawned with the cv::UMat version, having high CPU load as well.

I suspect that the CPU is constantly polling for the GPU result, without, for example sleeping between the checks, or blocking until there is a result, causing something like a busy-loop for the CPU.

Why is this happening? Is there a way to change this behavior in OpenCV, in order to free the CPU to perform useful work in parallel?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it is dividing work into cpu and gpu since you don't give and explicit command to work only gpu? cv::sum(mat)[0] is separable to multiple devices?

Comment: It's possible, but I think it's OpenCL/GPU only, the results are the same if I explicitly set the GPU using OPENCV_OPENCL_DEVICE in environment. Also, most of the CPU time is not in user space, but kernel time (system, IO wait).

Comment: %100 on all cores or a single core?

Comment: On one system with 4 cores it's 50% + 50%, on another with 12, it's 100% + 90% + 40% + 10% , for example. That's bad, because in the real app, if the cores are already almost fully utilized, the GPU can not help to do additional work in parallel, because it heavily affects the CPU even for GPU-intensive work.